# What are my options if a scraper found and published one of my posts that I have since deleted?

Tags: discussion, editing-help, copycat-sites

I have deleted an old question that I posted on Stack Overflow quite a time back, but it still shows at below location:

https://coredump.pt/questions/44386120/facing-oom-issue-with-twitter-finagle-rest-api

I also see a link on that post to my Stack Overflow user account, but I am not able to delete the post on said site.

What options do I have?

Comment: 1. Why would you deface [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386120) that was deleted more than one year ago?  2. [You didn't delete that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386120) - *"deleted by Community♦ Jun 9 '18 at 5:07 (RemoveAbandonedQuestions)"*.

Comment: there are some informations that were not suppose to be on public and i need to remove them.

Comment: Well you're most likely out of luck. Always consider carefully what you want to be out on the internet, and under what terms you put things on the internet. Also this question you posted now might invoke the Streissand effect.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like someone scraped the page, translated it, and posted their own copy. Since SE's [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licenced, and on the public Internet, and it does look like they've attributed  well...

There's not much SE can do except ask them nicely, and if it's following the licencing criteria, there's not much reason to - especially since they did what was asked of them - linking to both the question and the user. .

Since it's *not* an SE owned page, well, you can't really delete it yourself.

If you *really* need it gone because it's not supposed to be out in the wild, well, it's tough. If you're just trying to delete it because you deleted it on SO, it's a copy and it's got nothing to do with the SO copy.

Comment: somehow it still shows my user linked to that. otherwise i wouldnt have cared much :(

Comment: That's the "Attribution required"

Comment: Yes, the question attribution is also there, "[fonte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fonte#Noun_8)" at the lower left (presuming Portuguese, *"3. source (that from which something comes or is acquired)"*).

Comment: @RajeshRai You do still have the right under the license to demand removal of your name from the content, even if they refuse to delete it outright. It may not solve the problem completely for you, but it's an option. It does require figuring out a way to contact them though, if it's not obvious somewhere.